# python scrapy - extract data from <table> - no id tag

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Python and Scrapy that's why I created a project for myself to learn it. But at the moment I'm struggling to get the data from following page: [Website to crawl](https://www.immoscout24.ch/en/d/flat-buy-bevilard/4761145?s=2&t=2&l=436&r=40&se=16&ci=3&ct=1290)

As I could see with the "developer tools" from Chrome/Firefox there are 8 tables with the class like this: `<table class="sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE">`

In this picture [structure and table I'd like to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIQwR.jpg) you see the structure and the column (`<td>`) where the value is = "Wheelchair accessible" that I want to extract. The value is in the second column at it is a picture  tag.
It is to read like this: If I can find it (in this case "Wheelchair accessible"), the value equals true if I can't find it at all, then the value equals false.

I managed things around it like browsing through the parent-detail three of website. But now I can't browse to the correct XPATH to find this table with `class="sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"`

I tried to narrow it down to the very basics in the shell cmd:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/d/wohnung-kaufen-bevilard/4761145?s=2&t=2&l=436&r=40&se=16&ci=3&ct=1290'
tables = response.xpath('//*[@class="sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"]/table')
for table in tables[1:]:
    print("I found it!!") #this should be returned 8 times, once for each table
    table.xpath('tr/td[1]//text()').extract_first()
```

The full path to the Wheelchair accessible  is:
`//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/section/article[7]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

Unfortunately above code doesn't give anything back. I don't get any error, but also no print that I would expect.

1. What am I doing wrong? I imagine can't be that difficult?
2. Once I found the correct table, how would extract the data from the table to a JSON the easiest and fastest way? I imagine this will be quite slow, as basically I need to parse the whole HTML code several times to find if each property-description is there or not?

I appreciate all your help or any tips! I already invested a couple of days trying to figure it out..

Comment: If `"sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"` is a class name of `table` node, then XPath should be `//table[@class="sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"]` as `'//*[@class="sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"]/table'` means *`table` which is a direct child of some node with class name `"sc-fHxwqH ddWfJE"`*. Note that you should ask one question per ticket. If you have more questions - ask them in separate tickets

Comment: I did try your commands using scrapy shell, and your xpath works for me. `response.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/section/article[7]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]//text()').extract_first()` yields `'Rollstuhlgängig'` which is the german word for Wheelchair accessible :-) btw a quick way to find good xpaths is using XPath Helper extension for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Andersson, that worked very well. I thought I tried that as well but probably made a mistake. 
I will now try to solve question 2. and will post my answer as soon as I'm finished. Except someone has an answer to that as well feel free to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to request HTML, scrape node values and put them into JSON as required data already comes from API in JSON format

Simply try

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://react-api.immoscout24.ch/v1.3/properties/4761145?ci=3&ct=1290&l=436&lng=de&p=4761145&r=40&s=2&se=16&t=2"
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

Then you can get required data like

```
print(response['propertyDetails']['agency'])
```

Output:

```
{'companyCity': 'Bevilard', 'companyName1': 'avendre.ch ', 'companyName2': 'Agen
ce Berne', 'companyPhoneMobile': '078 868 60 64', 'companyStreet': 'Rue Principa
le 41', 'companyZip': '2735', 'email': 'berne@avendre.ch', 'firstName': 'Verena'
, 'gender': 'f', 'lastName': 'Pecaut-Steiner', 'logoUrl': 'https://www.immoscout
24.ch/resources/memberlogos/L356353-R.jpg', 'nameFormatted': 'Verena Pecaut-Stei
ner', 'webUrl': 'http://www.avendre.ch'}
```

Comment: That is absolutely astonishing! How did you find that, it's not even documented on their website:-). I googled a bit and found this [link](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api), I assume that's how you did it. Might help some others reading this, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sspaeti, all the data that appears on webpage most probably comes from HTTP requests, you can simply do F12 and switch to Network tab to check requests that your browser send to get dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly (check each `article` node with `h2` followed by `table`:

```
for table_node in response.xpath('//article/h2/following::*[1][name()="table"]'):
    #process each table here
```